# how to compare none English characters(Hebrew)

Tags: android, character-encoding, string-comparison, hebrew

I have tried to compare two Hebrew strings:

```
 for (String key : CsvReader.all_streets.keySet()){
      if(key.equals("אורנית"))
      {
           Log.w("Strings are", "equal");
      }
 }
```

and it failed. I thought it is somehow related to the encoding of the Hebrew language so i tried to compare using the same encoding(UTF-8) like:

```
for (String key : CsvReader.all_streets.keySet()){
     ByteBuffer key_encoded = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(key);
     ByteBuffer oranit = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode("אורנית");

     if(key_encoded.equals(oranit))
     {
          Log.w("Strings are", "equal");
     }
}
```

and it also didn't work. Just to make sure the string is in the collection, i have printed the HashMap using:

```
Log.wtf("Key is", key);
```

[image]

I read the collection `all_streets` from Real Time Database(firebase).
I searched on the internet for answer but i couldn't find anything related(besides Java strings are encoded as UTF-16).
How can i compare these two strings ?

Comment: Have you seen: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html

Comment: First thanks for replaying ! I tried to use it in the following way: `Collator hebrew_collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("iw","IL")); for (String key : CsvReader.all_streets.keySet()){  if(hebrew_collator.compare(key, "אורנית") == 0)
                      {
                          Log.wtf("Strings are", "equal");
                      }` and it also didn't work and the result was 1

Comment: And just to double check, the strings contain the same bytes as opposed to a hidden character somewhere?

Comment: Yes you right. After substringing `String key` and compare letter by letter i noticed that `String key` is way bigger then `"אורנית"`. It had extra white-space chars and for some reason `Log.wtf()` didn't show these extra white-space chars. After trimming the String comparison worked :)